# How to render an image by using gradient-domain screened and Poisson reconstruction

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, pixel, poisson

I am working on a project for my thesis and I am building my own path tracer. Afterwards, I have to modify it in such a way to be able to implement the following paper:

https://mediatech.aalto.fi/publications/graphics/GPT/kettunen2015siggraph_paper.pdf

Of course I DO NOT want you to read the paper, but I link it anyway for those who are more curious. In brief, instead of rendering an image by just using the normal path tracing procedure, I have to calculate the gradients for each pixel, which means: if before we were shooting only rays through each pixel, we now shoot also rays for the neighbouring pixels, 4 in total, left, right, top, bottom. Let me explain in other words, I shoot one ray through a pixel and calculate its final colour as for normal path tracing, but, moreover, I shoot rays for its neighbour pixels, calculate the same final colour for those and, in order to calculate the gradients, I subtract their final colours from the main pixel. It means that for each pixel I will have 5 values in total:

- colour of the pixel
- gradient with right pixel = colour of the right pixel - colour of the pixel
- gradient with left pixel = colour of the left pixel - colour of the pixel
- gradient with top pixel = colour of the top pixel - colour of the pixel
- gradient with bottom pixel = colour of the bottom pixel - colour of the pixel

The problem is that I don't know how to build the final image by both using the main colour and the gradients. What the paper says is that I have to use the screened Poisson reconstruction.

"Screened Poisson reconstruction combines the image and its
gradients using a parameter α that specifies the relative weights of
the sampled image and the gradients".

Everywhere I search for this Poisson reconstruction I see, of course, a lot of math but it comes hard to apply it to my project. Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question smells fishy to me.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Excuse me?

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/poisson

Comment: still don't get it sorry, but as you prefer

Comment: Well it's not complicated, is it? "Poisson" is the French for "fish". I was making a joke. Regretting it now.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ahahah I apologize then :D I am sorry!!